# Using ngIF in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I used to use ngshow when I wanted to hide or show divs in ionic 1.

I'm using ionic 3 and I'm trying to make the button do nothing (no click event) if the indexCount == 0.

I currently have...

```
<div ng-if=" indexCount == 0">
<button ion-button class="previous"> Previous </button>

<div ng-if=" indexCount != 0">
 <button ion-button class="next" (click)="previousButtonClick"> Next 
</button>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that you want to disable or hide the 'previous' button on the page with `indexCount == 0` and disable/hide 'next' button on the last page `indexCount == length - 1` where `length` is the number of pages.

You can either disable a button for consistent layout

```
<button [disabled]="indexCount == 0" ion-button class="previous">Previous</button>
<button [disabled]="indexCount >= length - 1" ion-button class="next" (click)="previousButtonClick()">Next</button>
```

or remove it with `*ngIf`

```
<button *ngIf="indexCount != 0" ion-button class="previous">Previous</button>
<button *ngIf="indexCount < length - 1" ion-button class="next" (click)="previousButtonClick()">Next</button>
```

Note that `[disabled]` prevents click events firing.

Answer (score 2):

As of Angular2 you need to use `*ngIf`, you can see an example [here](https://alligator.io/angular/ngif-directive/).
**Example:**

```
<div *ngIf=" indexCount == 0">
  <button ion-button class="previous"> Previous </button>
</div>
<div *ngIf=" indexCount != 0">
  <button ion-button class="next" (click)="previousButtonClick">
    Next 
 </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For this situation you can also use the [ng-template.](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/)

**Exemple:**

```
<ng-template #thenTemplateClick>
  <button ion-button class="next" (click)="previousButtonClick()">
    Next 
  </button>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #elseTemplateClick>
  <button ion-button class="previous"> Previous </button>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of doing this could be to add a condition on the button's function in the .ts file. On the template file:

```
<button ion-button (click)='myButtonAction()>Previous</button>
```

On the .ts file:

```
    myButtonAction(){
        if(this.indexCount == 0){
             console.log('No Action');
        } else {
             // Previous Button Desired Action
             // eg NavCtrl action or change value to trigger *ngIf update etc
        }
    }
```